# Scraping with out Selenium Webdriver stealing focus

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using Selenium to automate a website. First, I open the main website with C#. 
Then, I manually click to open new windows from the main site. Now, I want to scrape the data of these new windows. This is not an issue. The problem lies in the fact that Selenium seems to need a window to be focused to scrape it. I use the SwitchTo method currently before scraping. When you switch, the new windows pop to the front and steal focus from other windows. Is there a way to scrape a window without giving it focus?

Comment: Why clicking manually? put all on selenium and C#.

Answer (score 1):

Saying that “Selenium requires focus when scraping a page” is a gross oversimplification at best, and a complete misassignment if responsibility at worst. Whether a driver used by Selenium to automate a page requires focus is highly dependent on the driver’s implementation. You haven’t said what browser you’re using, but if it’s Chrome or Firefox, those implementations are created and maintained by the browser vendors (Google and Mozilla, respectively).

There are alternatives in both cases, as both browsers officially support a “headless” mode, which can be used with Selenium. Note, however, that use of that mode would require you to automate the steps you’re currently doing manually.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful note. So does that essentially means `IEDriverServer` doesn't requires focus? In that case how should we interpret **`REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS`** which says `Capability that defines to focus to browser window or not before operation.`?

Comment: The `requireWindowFocus` capability applies only to IE, and should only apply to interaction with elements (click, sendKeys, etc.). However, that’s not a guarantee, and again, you neglected to mention which browser you were attempting to use in your question. My recommendation would be to use one of the other browsers’ “headless” options to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Answering straight, **No** Selenium can't scrape a window without the required focus.

> It's not only **`Selenium`** needs focus. The **`WebElements`** with whom you intend to interact with, needs to be within the [**`Viewport`**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

### Update:

As per your comment if you want to work through an alternatives to Selenium that wouldn't require focus the Answer is [**`Beautiful Soup`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) through **`Selenium Python Clients`** using **`urllib.request`** module.

Comment: Do you know of any alternatives to Selenium that wouldn't require focus?